# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE & ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

Tags: android

In my application, I am using "android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE & ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE" intents to take pictures and videos which will then be send over to the backend.

How do I retrieve the default pathname of the intents? One way is to use "putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)" but then if I take a picture it is saved twice, one in the specified uri and another in the dafault path (/sdcard/DCIM/CAMERA...).

Is there any way where after taking the picture (the sending to the backend is already done) I can retrieve the default path and then delete that image/video?

Also I noticed that when calling "protected void onActivity (int requestcode ....)", I can only do so for either the camera or video intent. Within the same method, the application crashes.

How do I handle multiple intents?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to store Image in default location then start native camera app using following coding snippet

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camera, PHOTO_REQCOD);
```

In Your OnActivityResult callback you can retrieve bitmap as follows.

```
Bundle b = data.getExtras();
Bitmap bitmap_photo =  (Bitmap) b.get("data");
```

I did this in one of projects.
Enjoy..

Comment: I want to store the image in the default location but want to retrieve the location of the picture stored. Is there any way this can be achieved?